# Drum score using musixper package from Musixtex

Tags: tikz-pgf, musixtex, musixper

It is needed to implement a drum score for Bass Drum, Ride, Hi-Hat, Snare, Clave, Cow Bell, The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, math}
\usepackage{amsmath}%Para signo igual
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas


\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
      \largemusicsize
      \setlines{1}{5}
      %\setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
      \setclefsymbol{1}{\drumclef}%
      \nobarnumbers
      \nostartrule
      \startextract
      \NOtes\zql f\doqu m\en
      \NOtes\doql d\ibu0m0\doqb0{m}\en
      \NOtes\tbu0\doqb0m\en
      \NOtes\qu j\en
      \NOtes\dcqu j\en
      \NOtes\roql j\en
      \NOtes\tgql l\en
      \endextract
\end{music} 

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output is as follow:
[image: desired]

Comment: Have you tried anything with zcharnotes and shifting notes backwards with \bsk or forwards with \hsk? Please show your efforts by editing your question, if any question then remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be my solution within MusiXTeX:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{spanish}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, math}
    \usepackage{amsmath}%Para signo igual
    \usepackage{musicography}
    \usepackage{musixtex} 
    \input{musixlyr}
    \input {musixcho}
    \input {musixdat}%fecha
    \input {musixfll}
    \input {musixgre}%gregoriano
    \input {musixper}%percusión
    \input {musixppff}
    \input {musixstr}
    \input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
    \input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
    
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{music}
    \hsize=140mm%
        \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
          \largemusicsize
          \setlines{1}{5}
          %\setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
          \setclefsymbol{1}{\drumclef}%
          \nobarnumbers
          \nostartrule
      %    \startextract
      \startpiece%
      \addspace{0.5\afterruleskip}%
          \notes\ccharnote  J{\A ~Bass Drum}\ccharnote t{\A ~Ride}\zql f\doqu m\hsk\ccharnote J{\A ~Hi-Hat \it (foot)}\ccharnote t{~$\circ$}\ccharnote w{\it ~open}\ccharnote z{\hsk\qsk\A ~Hi-Hat}\doql d\bsk\ibu0m0\doqb0{m}\ccharnote u{~+}\ccharnote w{\it ~closed}\tbu0\doqb0m\ccharnote t{\A ~Snare}\qu j\ccharnote w{\A ~Snare}\ccharnote t{\A ~rimshot}\dcqu j\ccharnote t{\A ~Clave}\roql j\ccharnote t{\A Cow Bell}\tgql l\en\setdoublebar%
          \endpiece%
    \end{music}%
    
    \end{document}%
```

I defined a hsize to avoid shifting notes or define distances by using capitals too often.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solved code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, math}
\usepackage{amsmath}%Para signo igual
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas


\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
      \largemusicsize
      \setlines{1}{5}
      %\setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
      \setclefsymbol{1}{\drumclef}%
      \nobarnumbers
      \nostartrule
      \startextract
      \NOTes\zcharnote{-12}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-1.1cm} Bass Drum}\zql f\doqu m\zcharnote{17}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-1.6cm} Ride}\en
      \znotes\hsk\doql d\en
      \NOTes\zcharnote{16}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} $\circ$}\ibu0m0\doqb0{m}\zcharnote{16}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} $+$}\en
      \NOTes\tbu0\doqb0m\en
      \NOTes\qu j\en
      \NOTes\dcqu j\en
      \NOTes\roql j\en
      \NOTes\tgql l\en
      \endextract
\end{music} 

\end{document}
```

I think there is an easy way to add labels using Tikz with annotate library. Also the triangule needs fill.

The output is as follow:

[image: solved]

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to add text using tikzmark. The solved code needs additional horizontal and vertical shift inside pic cs:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, math}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\NewDocumentCommand{\addU}{mm}{\tikz[remember picture]{\node[overlay,above=of pic cs:#1]{#2};}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\addB}{mm}{\tikz[remember picture]{\node[overlay,below=of pic cs:#1]{#2};}}
\usepackage{amsmath}%Para signo igual
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas


\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
      \largemusicsize
      \setlines{1}{5}
      \setclefsymbol{1}{\drumclef}%
      \nobarnumbers
      \nostartrule
      \startextract
      \NOTes\tikzmark{BD}\zql f\tikzmark{R}\doqu m\en
      \znotes\hsk\tikzmark{HH}\doql d\en
      \NOTes\tikzmark{HHH}\zcharnote{16}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} $\circ$}\ibu0m0\doqb0{m}\zcharnote{16}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} $+$}\en
      \NOTes\tbu0\doqb0m\en
      \NOTes\tikzmark{S}\qu j\en
      \NOTes\tikzmark{SR}\dcqu j\en
      \NOTes\tikzmark{C}\roql j\en
      \NOTes\tikzmark{CB}\tgql l\en
      \endextract
\end{music} 
\addU{R}{Ride}
\addU{S}{Snare}
\addU{HHH}{Hi-Hat}
\addB{BD}{Bass Drum}
\addB{HH}{Hi-Hat (foot)}
%\addU{SR}{Snare\\rimshot}
\addU{C}{Clave}
\addU{CB}{Cow Bell}

\end{document}
```

[image: solved_partially]

Some help on how add aditional shift on: above=of pic cs:#1, is welcome !!!

Comment: I mean: above=of pic cs:#1 ++(0,2ex)  doesn't work !!!

Answer (score 0):

The solved code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, math}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\NewDocumentCommand{\addU}{mm}{\tikz[remember picture]{\node[overlay,above=10mm of pic cs:#1]{#2};}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\addUH}{mm}{\tikz[remember picture]{\node[overlay,above=14mm of pic cs:#1]{#2};}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\addUHH}{mm}{\tikz[remember picture]{\node[overlay,above=18mm of pic cs:#1]{#2};}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\addUHHH}{mm}{\tikz[remember picture]{\node[overlay] at ($(pic cs:#1)+(0.85cm,2.2cm)$) {#2};}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\addB}{mm}{\tikz[remember picture]{\node[overlay,below=of pic cs:#1]{#2};}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\addBB}{mm}{\tikz[remember picture]{\node[overlay,below=14mm of pic cs:#1]{#2};}}
\usepackage{amsmath}%Para signo igual
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixper}%percusión

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
      \largemusicsize
      \setlines{1}{5}
      \setclefsymbol{1}{\drumclef}%
      \nobarnumbers
      \nostartrule
      \startextract
      \NOTes\tikzmark{BD}\zql f\tikzmark{R}\doqu m\en
      \znotes\hsk\tikzmark{HH}\doql d\en
      \NOTes\tikzmark{HHH}\zcharnote{16}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} $\circ$}\ibu0m0\doqb0{m}\zcharnote{16}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.08cm} $+$}\en
      \NOTes\tbu0\doqb0m\en
      \NOTes\tikzmark{S}\qu j\hsk\en
      \NOTes\tikzmark{SR}\dcqu j\hsk\en
      \NOTEs\tikzmark{C}\roql j\hsk\en
      \NOTEs\tikzmark{CB}\tgql l\en
      \endextract
\end{music} 
\addUH{R}{Ride}
\addUH{S}{Snare}
\addUHHH{HHH}{Hi-Hat}
\addB{BD}{Bass Drum}
\addBB{HH}{Hi-Hat (foot)}
\addUH{SR}{Snare\newline rimshot}
\addU{C}{Clave}
\addU{CB}{Cow Bell}

\end{document}
```

[image: solved_near]

It is remaining the newline of the command:
\addUH{SR}{Snare\newline rimshot}
Some help is welcome !!!

Comment: Please unaccept your answer. You are not satisfied yourself, and you are lacking the "open" and "closed" for the Hi-Hat.